# Can't place Floating Action Button (FAB) between header and items in DrawerLayout using RecyclerView

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I can't get the Floating Action Button (FAB) to appear in the correct position.  I want it to appear between the header and the first item in my nav drawer.

[image]

Currently, I've got it to appear in the bottom right corner of the header and NOT on top of the line between the 1st and 2nd elements (1st element = header & 2nd element = first item in recyclerview).

My app is using the following appcompat items:

- appcompat-v7:23.0.0
- recyclerview-v7:23.0.0
- design:23.0.0

I'm using a nav drawer but I can't use the NavigationView because I need to customize the item entries and not load a simple menu.

As you know, the drawer is really not 2 different controls.  The header is actually the '0' element in the RecyclerView.  I don't know if this makes a difference.

Here is my current xml for the header/"0 view in RecyclerView":

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/navdrawer_image_height">


    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/navDrawerHeaderView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/navdrawer_image_height">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/navdrawer_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/navdrawer_image_height"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd_navdrawer_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_material_design" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/app_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_user_picture_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/navdrawer_user_picture_size"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:border_width="2dp"
            app:border_color="#FF000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/appNameTextView"
            android:text="App Name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/button_account"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/navDrawerHeaderView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:elevation="4dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I think I might have the FAB in the wrong location/file.  Here is the xml for the drawer.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Content layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/init_background">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Pages -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

HELP!!!!!

Comment: Normally, you should not place FAB inside a Drawer. FAB is used for a promoted positive actions. But drawer is intended for navigation!

Comment: Agreed.  I think it's appropriate in this situation.  I want to place an options menu (of sorts).  I could add it to the bottom of the drawer but I think it looks better and makes more sense as a FAB.  Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: There's no way that a view can be outside of a view that it is in. I think you would need to move your header outside of the recyclerview into an `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: How would that look?

Comment: maybe this `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"` change it to `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|start"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

example drawer fragment layout containing your existing `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:id="@+id/header"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Nice solution! For `FAB` I suggest to use `layout_margin` as `16dp` for phones and `24dp` for tablets